# Calculate the area between two polygons

Tags: function, math, polygon, area, autocad

I got two list of points (x,y of each point).
I need to find the area (if any) between the two.
I do understand that if no line intersect, it does not mean that there is no are. One can be fully inside the other.
I need it for autocad vba

Any help?

Comment: "it does not mean that there is no are": please write in English.

Comment: it does not mean that there is no join area

Comment: You probably mean no common area then.

Answer (score 0):

This problem requires to construct the intersection polygon and compute its area (which can be made of several pieces) for instance by means of the shoelace formula. The first operation is far from being trivial. I can refer you to the Clipper library http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php.

The problem can be simpler if your polygons have special properties.

But doesn't AutoCAD have such a functionality built-in ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the BooleanOperation function of the Entity object.